# Datetime Month using string in flutter

Tags: flutter

is there any way to make the month of datetime in flutter showing by name of month not showing the number?

i have searching it before, but there is nothing like what i search.

example : 
if i'm using dd-MM-yyyy then it showing => 29-12-2019

is there any way to change it to : 29-dec-2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra `M` to the pattern `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

you can also change the pattern like this `d-MMM-y`

Use `DateFormat` from `package:intl/intl.dart`

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
//...
var now = new DateTime.now();
final df = new DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy');

print(df.format(now));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the String `'29-12-2019'` to `'29-dec-2019'` then You can first convert the string to `DateTime` format then make it to the proper format you want.

```
DateTime date=DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", "en_US").parse("29-12-2019"));
final df = new DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy');
print(df.format(date));
```